# Is there a Textexpander-liker feature in OSX?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard

I thought I heard that snow leopard had a built-in text expander.

Is it true?

Do you know how I could access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Text*.
[image]

---

Press `Tab` after typing a shortcut to perform the replace.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use tab. It should do the replacing automatically with just space.

Comment: Ha! just found this as a replacement for the memory-leaking 3rd party solution I was using - Brilliant :)